# how to solve the HTML/CSS property overflowing a section on mobile renders

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have two main containers on my webpage: `1.<div class="main">` and `2.<section class="main-cars">`.

My `<div class="main">`, the very first content of my webpage, is a Vimeo integration of a video playing in the background (behind some titles). This container renders perfectly on computers, and on all responsive devices **simulated on a computer**. However, when it comes to loading the page on my smartphone, the 1. container overflows a bit of the 2. container. Attached the screenshots:
[image: How it is on my smartphone]

And here is how it should be, and how it is when emulated with Responsive Viewer:
[image: How it should be]

As you can see, the linear gradient applied on my 1. container overflows my second section (the white one).  This is very annoying to solve because it is happening only on mobiles, not emulated mobiles on computers.

```css
.main {
  top: 0;
  background-color: #111111 i !important;
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: 60em;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.header-c {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-top: 0.2333333333rem !important;
  padding-bottom: 0.175rem !important;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.container-main {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: flex-end;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.cont {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.ttt {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-right: 5em;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 10em;
}

.fluids {
  position: absolute !important;
  display: flex !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 177.777778vh !important;
}

.vid {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.fluidvids-item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

img,
video,
iframe {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}


/* SECTION CODE*/

.main-cars {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="header-c">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo-c">
        <img src="FinanceUI.png" alt="" class="logo">
        <div class="logo-title-c">
          <span class="logo-m">Ghost-Cars</span>
          <span class="loc-logo">Paris - Cannes - Monaco</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-main">
    <div class="cont">
      <div class="ttt">
        <div class="c-c">Luxury Cars Rentals <br class="br"> with style.</div>
        <div class="lang-c">
          <p class="lang">Français</p>
          <p class="lang underline">English</p>
          <p class="lang">Polski</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fluids">
      <div class="vid">
        <iframe id="recruiting-video-cover" class="transition-opacity fluidvids-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/823655290?h=114a4fac97&amp;autopause=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;background=1&amp;loop=1&amp;muted=1&amp;playsinline=1&amp;transparent=1&amp;texttrack=false;app_id=58479"
          width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen="" style="pointer-events: none; opacity: 1;" title="Join us in shaping the future of technology" data-fluidvids="loaded" data-ready="true" autoplay=1 loop=1></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<section class="main-cars">
  <!-- SOME CODE-->
</section>
```

I tried to apply a `position: relative;`, the result is on the screens. Also, with a z-index: 100; the section 2. comes above the main div, so it works but overflows the 1. container: not a solution.

If needed, the website is located here: financeui.org

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are using `min-height:100vh` in your `.container-main` div. I can't really test it, but I am almost sure that if you remove that you should be fine.